# Hard elementary-number-theory question on solve all $n$s that make $2^6+2^{10}+2^n$ a square numbe

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

I want to know all the nonnegative integer $n$ that makes $2^6+2^{10}+2^n$ be some other integer's square.

I have tried it numerically for a range from $0$ to $1000$, and only $0,9,11,12,15$ returns to be satisfying the condition.

I believe the above is all the solution, but I need a formal proof.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to specify that $n$ itself must also be an integer, otherwise an infinite number of solutions can be proved easily.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but it may help analyzing the problem:

$\exists n>15$ such that $2^6+2^{10}+2^n$ is a perfect square $\iff$

$\exists n>15$ such that $2^6(2^0+2^4+2^{n-6})$ is a perfect square $\iff$

$\exists n>15$ such that $64(17+2^{n-6})$ is a perfect square $\iff$

$\exists n>15$ such that $17+2^{n-6}$ is a perfect square $\iff$

$\exists m>9$ such that $17+2^m$ is a perfect square

---

So an equivalent but simplified question would be:

Is $17+2^m$ a perfect square only for a positive integer $m=3,5,6,9$?

Comment: @Geoff Robinson: My answer explicitly states $n>15$.

Comment: OK, I had not noticed that small cases had already been checked

Comment: Sorry. Are you suggesting the proof is now easy after you showed the simplified form of the question? If so, please execuse my ignorance as I still cannot see it.

Comment: @1111111: I did not suggest that, as I wrote at the beginning of the answer - "This is not a direct answer to your question, but it may help analyzing the problem". It was just too complicated to be written as a comment to your question.

Comment: The equivalent question has an answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2298402

Answer (score 1):

$2^n$ is either a square, $p^2$, or twice a square, $2q^2$, depending on whether $n$ is even or odd.

17 can only be the difference between two squares in a small number of ways.

So you are left solving the Pell-type equation $2q^2+17=r^2$

Comment: The Pell-type equation will yield a general form like $(5+2\sqrt2)(3+2\sqrt2)^n$ or $(5-2\sqrt2)(3+2\sqrt2)^n$ but that does not complete the solution because you still have to show that when $q$ is a solution to $r^2-2q^2=17$ AND $q=2^l$ for some $l\geq0$ then the general solution reduces down to only a few finite solutions.

Comment: Perhaps $q\pmod 8$ is never zero

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you.

Comment: The solutions to the Pell-type equation form a sequence $(q_n,r_n)$. There is a simple recursion that relates $(q_n,r_n)$ to $(q_{n-1},r_{n-1})$.  Look at the remainders of $q_n$ modulo 8 or 16, and they might repeat without hitting zero.