# Finding solutions to $2^x+17=y^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Find all positive integer solutions $(x,y)$ of the following equation: 
>   $$2^x+17=y^2.$$

If $x = 2k$, then we can rewrite the equation as $(y - 2^k)(y + 2^k) = 17$, so the factors must be $1$ and $17$, and we must have $x = 6, y = 9$.

However, this approach doesn't work when $x$ is odd.

Comment: This is a [Ramanujan Nagell Type equation.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjP44frno_UAhVM2SYKHUkyDzQQFggxMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FRamanujan%25E2%2580%2593Nagell_equation&usg=AFQjCNFpN2Ie0QRVDhCIm-UUtlpz_VXu9g)

Comment: @Guan_ts: Based on Nil's comment, it seems that the case where $x$ is odd would probably require to advanced methods, so it's surely not an assigned problem, is it?

Comment: if you have python you can generate them with: `for n in range(1, 1000, 2): \n if sqrt(2 ** n + 17).is_integer(): \n print(n)` (insert line break and indent at `\n`)

Comment: @Dando18 yea, python is a good tool for intuition and checking for small numbers. But here the question is about "all positive integer", and the problem is that most of the integers are larger than 1000, and most integers are larger than 100000000000000000000000....

Comment: @YujieZha hence why it is just a comment. At least for me, seeing a pattern in finite numbers can _often_ lead to intuition for the infinite case.

Comment: There exist solutions with $x$ odd, for example $x = 3$ and $y = 5$.

Comment: @Dando18 Yea, I agree. That's why I say it's good for intuition, as long as we know its limitations :)

Comment: @TobErnack $x=3,5,9$ are the only solutions less than 10,000 (checked by mathematica)

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says that $x=3,5,6,9$ are the only solutions.

Comment: 3,5 and 9 have solutions.  Other solutions would require y +/- 1=2n, y-/+1=8m, nm =2^{x-4}+1 but I can't get anywhere with that.

Comment: We have $17 = 5^2-2^3 $ as well as $17=3^2+2^3$ and as "bonus" also $17 = 9^2-2^6 $    (because  $= (3^2+2^3)(3^2-2^3)$ and $(3^2-2^3)=1$ ) . Moreover, if $x$ is even then $2^x$ is a square and the possible cases where the difference between two squares is $17$ can be enumerated.

Comment: I have added additional "context" to the problem (an edit that has yet to be approved) that will hopefully satisfy voters. It's a shame that anybody would have voted to close this question in the first place.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo My edit was not intended to address the author. It was intended to add "context" so that the question would become acceptable. Lack of context was the stated reason for closing the question.

Comment: I'm glad to see this question was reopened.

Comment: I'm a beginner and an English learner. I don't know how this problem has been shelved.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help and hope that the problem can be solved.

Comment: Please see the comments below my answer. It should probably be unaccepted due to being incomplete.

Comment: I have graphed the equation the OP is trying to solve, it could give a hint: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/12th24cois

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The only solutions are $x = 3, 5, 6, 9$. This is proved on pp. 148-152 of

> Tzanakis, N. (1983), On the diophantine equation $y^2-D = 2^k$, *J. Number Theory* 17, 144-64.

Comment: Public copy of the paper http://users.math.uoc.gr/~tzanakis/Papers/y%5e2-D=2%5ek.pdf (see Corollary page 151)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like I need to spell out the details for insipidintegrator.

If $x$ is even, the prime $17$ is the product of $y+2^{x/2}$ and $y-2^{x/2}.$ Averaging, we find $y=9$ whence $x=6.$

If $x$ is odd, write $y-2^{x/2}=\frac{17}{y+2^{x/2}}$. Letting $x=2n+1$, we have
$\Big|\frac{y}{2^n}-\sqrt{2}\Big|=\frac{17}{2^n(y+2^{n+.5})}.$
From Beuker's thesis, If $q=2^k, \ \Big|\frac{p}{q}-\sqrt{2}\Big|>2^{-43.9}q^{-1.8}$ Thus $\Big|p-q\sqrt{2}\Big|>2^{-43.9}q^{.2}$
In our case, $p=y,q=2^n$ so $p+q\sqrt{2}>2q\sqrt{2}.$ Multiplying, $$17=y^2-2^x>2^{-43.9}q^{.2}\cdot 2q\sqrt{2}$$ or $$q^{1.2}<17\cdot2^{42.4}$$
and $$n<38.73955$$ A computer check shows the only solutions are $n=1,2,4.$ These values correspond to $x=3,5,9.$

Answer (score 1):

A largely complete answer:

Starting from $2^x+17=y^2$, we obtain $2^x+2^4=(y-1)(y+1)$. By observation, $x=4$ fails as $33\ne y^2$. Note that $(y-1),(y+1)$ are two consecutive even numbers, so their difference is $2$, and one of them contains a single factor of $2$ while the other contains more than one factor of $2$.

Case 1, $x<4 \Rightarrow x=1,2,3$: Hence, $2^x+2^4=18,20,24$. Of these, only $24=4\times 6$ is the product of two consecutive even numbers. This corresponds to $x=3$.

Case 2, $x>4$: $16(2^{x-4}+1)=(y-1)(y+1)$. We see $(2^{x-4}+1)$ is an odd number, which we can factor as $ab$, where both $a,b$ are odd integers $\ge 1$. It must be the case that $(y-1)(y+1)=8a\cdot 2b$ where $8a-2b=\pm 2$, or $4a-b=\pm 1 \Rightarrow b=4a\pm 1$ and $(2^{x-4}+1)=ab=4a^2\pm a$

For $a=1$ we get $4a^2\pm a=3,5$ corresponding to $2^1+1$ and $2^2+1$, whence $x-4=1,2 \Rightarrow x=5,6$

For $a=3$ we get $4a^2\pm a=33,39$. Of these, $33=2^5+1 \Rightarrow x-4=5 \Rightarrow x=9$

I note that for $x\ge 9 \Rightarrow x-4 \ge 5$ it is the case that $(2^{x-4}+1) \equiv 1 \bmod 32$ and $a$ being odd means $a^2 \equiv 1 \bmod 8 \Rightarrow 4a^2 \equiv 4 \bmod 32$. Thus $(2^{x-4}+1)=4a^2\pm a \Rightarrow 4 \pm a \equiv 1 \bmod 32$, or $a\equiv \pm 3 \bmod 32$. Looking at the first $200$ members of $\{3,29,35,61,67,\dots\}$ I find no further suitable values of $a$

For larger $a$, I have not found a proof that none exist. If I find such a proof, I will update this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a computer and some luck, you can solve the problem "When will $a^n+b$ become a square number?". $a$ need not be prime.

Srinivasa Ramanujan said,

"The natural number solution of $2^n-7=m^2$ is only $(m, n) = (1, 3), (3, 4), (5, 5), (11, 7), (181, 15)$’’.

This was proved by Thoralf Skolem in 1959 and is known as the Ramanujan-Skolem theorem.
We can also prove Ramanujan-Skolem theorem in the following way.

Let’s prove $2^z+17=x^2$ has only natural number solutions $(x,z)=(5,3), (7,5), (9,6), (23,9)$.

It's easy when $z$ is even.
When $z$ is an odd number, just solve $x^2-2y^2=17$.
Algorithms based on quadratic field theory are known, and all possible integer $y$ are represented by the sequence of integers $k$
$$y_k＝\pm\{(4+5\sqrt{2})(3+2\sqrt{2})^k+(4-5\sqrt{2})(3-2\sqrt{2})^k\}/4.$$

Focusing on the maximum number of times $y_k$ is divisible by $2$, I calculated it with a software called "Maxima":
$$k≡1 \bmod 2 \Leftrightarrow y_k\equiv0\bmod 4$$
$$k≡1 \bmod 4 \Leftrightarrow y_k\equiv0\bmod 8$$
$$k≡1 \bmod 8 \Leftrightarrow y_k\equiv0\bmod 16$$
$$k≡9 \bmod 16 \Leftrightarrow y_k\equiv0\bmod 32$$
$$k≡25 \bmod 32 \Leftrightarrow y_k\equiv0\bmod 64$$
$$k≡25 \bmod 64 \Leftrightarrow y_k\equiv0\bmod 128$$
$$\cdots$$
$$k≡25 \bmod 1024\Leftrightarrow y_k\equiv0\bmod 2048$$
$$k≡1049\bmod2048\Leftrightarrow y_k\equiv0\bmod4096...(*)$$
$$k≡3097 \bmod 4096 \Leftrightarrow y_k\equiv0\bmod 8192$$
$$\cdots$$
As you can see, there is a structure in which a term that is divisible by a power of 2 always appears at intervals of powers of 2.
Introduced in
[$p$-adic structure of Pell-type equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4206840/p-adic-structure-of-pell-type-equations)
about this mechanism

(*) is used.
Since $y_k$ satisfies the recurrence formula between adjacent triplets $y_{k+1}=6y_k-y_{k-1}$,
$$y_{-999}\equiv  y_{1049}\equiv0\bmod4096,\ y_{-1000}\equiv y_{1048}\equiv\pm3538\bmod4096$$
From this, we can see that the remainder modulo 4096 has a period of 2048, and we can confirm with a computer that all the remaining 2046 terms from $y_{-998}$ to $y_{1047}$ are not divisible by 4096.
If you want to prove this result without using a calculator, you can use "$p$-adic log", which is discussed in the above URL, to actually show it by hand calculation, and you can also make a more sophisticated proof.

Now, although it is abrupt, for the Fermat prime $p = 2^{16} + 1 = 65537$, in the same order of symbols,
$$y_{1049}\equiv\pm17588\bmod p,\ y_{-999}\equiv y_{3097}\equiv\pm(-17588)\bmod p,$$
$$y_{1048}\equiv\pm21502\bmod p,\ y_{-1000}\equiv y_{3096}\equiv\pm(-21502)\bmod p$$

This looks like a "coincidence".
Since $y_k\bmod p$ has a period of 4096, $y_k\bmod p$ must be either $17588$ or $-17588$ for $k$ that satisfies $k\equiv1049\bmod2048$.

$2^{16}\equiv-1\bmod p$, so if $y_k$ is a power of 2, it should be $y_k^{16}\equiv\pm1\bmod p$.
But since $y_k^{16}\equiv(\pm17588)^{16}\equiv 42987\bmod p$, $y_k$ is never a power of 2 and a multiple of 4096 .

Finally, how to discover the above "coincidence"?

In general, the solution of the trinomial recurrence is
$$y_k=\alpha(A+B\sqrt{s})^k+\beta(A-B\sqrt{s})^k$$

If you want a prime $p$ such that $y_k\bmod p$ has period $N$, calculate
$$(A+B\sqrt{s})^N-1=C+D\sqrt{s}$$
and find the prime factors of $\gcd(C,D)$ that look good.

Answer (score -1):

$x=3,5,9$ work with $y=5,7,23$ but fail nor $x=1,7$.  If $x $ works for any other value then $x>4$.

$2^x+17=y^2$

$2^4 (2^{x-4}+1)=y^2-1=(y+1)(y-1) $

$y\pm 1$ must be even and $\gcd(x+1,x-1)=2$ and one is a multiple of $4$ while the other isn't.

That means::

$y\pm 1=8m;y\mp 1=2n;mn=2^{x-4}+1$

Also means

$2^x+8=y^2-9$

$2^3 (2^{x-3}+1)=(y-3)(y+3) $

So $y\mp 3 =4k=2n\mp 2;y\pm 3=2j=8m\pm 2;jk=2^{x-3}+1$

We have strict limitation here it seems.  In that $m,n $ are relatively close to $j,k $ but their product is about half.

I'm too lazy to work out the details but there must be an upper limit to that being possible.

Also $2^x-8=2^3 (2^{x-3}-1)=y^2-25=(y-5)(y+5) $ and so $y\pm 2 =4r;y\mp 2=2s;rs=jk-2$

So.... it's a mess but we have clear limits.

I strongly suspect $x=9$ is the highest possible $x $.

Oh, and we have $2^x+1=(y-4)(y+4)\approx 16mn $.

Answer (score -3):

I think that there are not solutions for $x$ odd.

Indeed,

$y^2=2^x+17=2^{2k+1}+17=2 \cdot 4^k +17 \equiv 2+17 \equiv3 \mod4$, which cannot happen.

(If $x$ is of the form $x=2k$, then the equation can be easily written $(y-2^k)(y+2^k)=17$, and so we go on).

EDIT: Wrong solution!

Comment: ***Nota Bene:***  $2^3 + 17 = 8 + 17 = 25 = 5^2$; here $x = 3$, $y = 5$.  If I recall correctly, $3$ is odd.

Comment: $$2+17 \not\equiv3 \pmod4$$

Comment: Yeah....$2*4^k \equiv 0\not \equiv 2 \mod 4$, I'm afraid.  So we get $y^2\equiv 1 \mod 4$ which is not particularly rare.

Comment: " $$2+17 \not\equiv3 \pmod4$$" um, yes it is.  But $2^x+17\not \equiv 2+17 \mod 4$ (unless x=1)

Comment: It was a silly mistake ...